# Recreate the Google image layout

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js

I want to recreate the layout of a google page result

When you click on the image, a div take the full of width of your screen and a little triangle show up at the bottom of the image clicked

A tried to put the img in an other div but the div was between two image not under a row so the layout was really bad

I tried this

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="(item,index) in AllItem" :key="index">
      <img :src="item.profile_image_url" @click.prevent.stop="clickShowInfoStream()" />
      <div v-show="imgXL">
        <img :src="profile_image_urlXL" class="imgProfileXL" />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "item",
  data() {
    return {
      imgXL: false
    };
  },
  methods: {
    clickShowImgXL() {
      this.imgXL = !this.imgXL;
    }
  }
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.imgProfileXL {
  background-color: #19171c;
  width: 100%;
}
</style>
```

I expect, when you click on a img a div show smoothly the image bigger between two row like the google seach layout and the image cllicked got a little triangle also when you click on "nothing" the div close up

Comment: If you want to recreate the Google Image layout then do it. The point of Stack Overflow is to share your code that you're having problems with.

Comment: so what have you tried? What does your code look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use css position:absulote to get the code of  `<div v-show="imgXL">
        <img :src="profile_image_urlXL" class="imgProfileXL" />
      </div>` out of the current div-layout , so it do not effect you layout.